# Reactjs + VSC sudden colossal 'Module not found' errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio, github, visual-studio-code

My project was working 100% fine until I pushed it to Github & cloned it, suddenly I am experiencing a myriad of "Module not found: Can't resolve..." import errors.

Here's 1 example:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve './components' in '..src\layouts\Main'
```

Main.js

```
import { Sidebar, Topbar, Footer } from "./components";
```

Folder structure

```
src
├── layouts
│   ├── Main
│   │   ├── components
│   │       ├── Footer
│   │           ├── Footer.js
│   │       ├── Sidebar
│   │           ├── Sidebar.js
│   │       ├── Topbar
│   │           ├── Topbar.js
│   │   ├── Main.js
```

Update: 
How to import redux actions?

```
src
├── redux
│   │   ├── actions
│   │       ├── dataActions.js
│   │       ├── userActions.js
|   | - store.js
|   | - types.js
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: do you have an `index.js` in components exporting from `./Footer`, `./Sidebar` and `./Topbar`, or is that not needed any more? I would have expected to see `Footer` imported from `./components/Footer` in the above example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only import with the component name, when you have an `index.js` file in the folder `Footer`.

```
import { Sidebar, Topbar, Footer } from "./components";
```

You need to have this folder structurue:

```
src
├── layouts
│   ├── Main
│   │   ├── components
│   │       ├── Footer
│   │           ├── index.js
│   │       ├── Sidebar
│   │           ├── index.js
│   │       ├── Topbar
│   │           ├── index.js
│   │   ├── Main.js
```

Updated, because question was updated:

For different redux actions, you can have an `index.js` file in the `actions` folder, which does the importing of the actions. Like so:

Within actions create index.js with the actions:

```
import { dataActions } from './dataActionts'
import { userActions } from './userActions'
```

Comment: This seems to do the trick, however it's still a mystery as to why it was working for so long before & suddenly after cloning it gave the errors.                                                           Now, how would this work for importing redux actions?
I edited the post.

Comment: maybe you have linter installed which did the fix automatically or you have something set up in vs code, which auto fixes imports? I updated my answer for redux actions.

Comment: Ahhh! So what happened was during the process of pushing to Github & cloning, the jsconfig.json file which enables the use of Absolute Imports, got deleted. Mystery solved, thank you for the help!!